# laravel handlebars - how to embed another html page

Tags: laravel, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars in my laravel project. Now I need to update my handlebar to show a another web page.

my question is - how can I display/embed a html page inside my handlebar.

I tried this - but didnt work

```
< l ink rel= "import"  href="/path/to/anotherpage.html">
```